# How to write a query to get the number of times a choice is selected by users

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, chart.js, django-queryset

I want to count the number of times a choice is selected by users. Here is my model

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField


class MedicalHistory(models.Model):
    Anxiety = 'Anxiety'
    Arthritis = 'Arthritis'
    Asthma = 'Asthma'
    Anemia = 'Anemia'
    Cancer = 'Cancer'
    Corona_virus = 'Corona_virus'
    Diabetes = 'Diabetes'
    Ebola = 'Ebola'
    HIV = 'HIV'
    ILLNESS_CHOICES = (
        (Anxiety, "Anxiety"),
        (Arthritis, "Arthritis"),
        (Asthma, "Asthma"),
        (Anemia, "Anemia"),
        (Cancer, "Cancer"),
        (Corona_virus, "Corona_virus"),
        (Diabetes, "Diabetes"),
        (Ebola, "Ebola"),
        (HIV, "HIV"),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    illness = MultiSelectField(choices=ILLNESS_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    symptoms = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    additional_info = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    disability = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    medications = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Medical History'
```

Here I have a number of illnesses I want users to select from. A user can select more tan one illness. I want each illness to have a count, and every time the illness is selected it adds to the count. In my view I have

views.py

```
def pie_chart(request):
labels = []
data = []

queryset = MedicalHistory.objects.values('illness').annotate(count=Sum('user')).order_by('-count')
for entry in queryset:
    labels.append(entry['illness'])
    data.append(entry['count'])

    return JsonResponse(data={
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
    }) 

<QuerySet [{'illness': ['Asthma', 'Diabetes', 'Ebola'], 'count': 3}, {'illness': ['Anemia', 'Covid-19'], 'count': 2}]>
```

The query doesn't do what I want, as I am trying to plot it in a chart. It groups the illness I think because of the `values`. My template.html looks like this.

chart.html

```
{% block content %}
{% include 'sidebar.html' %}
<div id="container" style="width: 85%;">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: {{ labels|safe }},
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Overview of Medical History',
            data: {{ data|safe }},
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(225, 400, 64, 0.2)'

            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'

            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>

        </div>
     <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->
{% endblock %}
```

### Solution:

So I was able to solve this using python. I initialized a dict with the illnesses and setting their initial count as 0. Then I used values() returns a dictionary of illnesses saved in the db. The I looped through the queryset and concatenate 1 to the values of the illnesses. Then i passed the keys and values as labels and data respectively.

views.py

```
def pie_chart(request):
    count = {'Anxiety': 0, 'Arthritis': 0, 'Asthma': 0, 'Anemia': 0, 'Cancer': 0,
             'Corona_virus': 0, 'Diabetes': 0, 'Ebola': 0, 'HIV': 0
             }

    queryset = MedicalHistory.objects.values('illness')
    for entry in queryset:
        for values in entry['illness']:
            count[values] += 1

    labels = [*count.keys()]
    data = [*count.values()]

    return render(request, 'chart.html', {
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that at the database level if you're using a `MultiSelectField` because the underlying value is just stored as `CharField` in the database. So `values('illness')` will only group by **equal** strings, i.e. combinations of illnesses.

So either do this in python, after you've fetched all the instances: Initialize a dict of counters, loop through the instances in your queryset and update the counters one by one. Note: This won't scale when the number of `MedicalHistory` rows in your table becomes large.

Or model your `Illness` as a separate model (don't use `MultiSelectField`), use a `ManyToMany` relationship and count those. Then you can do this in a queryset. This will scale with a very large number of rows.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I was able to do it by intializing a dict with the illnesses. Thanks

Comment: The problem with the python solution is that it doesn't scale well. If you have millions of entries, it requires you to fetch all entries in memory first. And it'll be slow.

Comment: Yes definitely. Also because it’ll let you dynamically add new illnesses just by adding them via the admin site.